# Question about GEV

Tags: probability, distributions, extreme-value

I'm doing some analysis involving rectangular pulse processes.
Suppose for each process `{Xi}` that `X` changes after equal so-called elementary
intervals of time `ti`. Therefore a reference period T (e.g. 1 year) is
divided into `ni` intervals of equal length `ti = T/ni`. Suppose that `X` is constant in each elementary interval and that `X` in the elementary intervals are identically distributed and mutually independent random variables with a density function (point-in-time distribution) `fx`, which belongs to the family of GEV distributions.

Now for `X1` let's say we have `t1, n1 and fx1`

for `X2` we have `t2, n2` (`n2>n1` and `n2/n1=integer`) and `fx2`

for `X3` we have `t3, n3` (`n3>n2` and `n3/n2=integer` and `n3/n1`=integer) and `fx3`

If I want to find the process `fx` for `X=X1+X2+X3`. With respect to `T` is it equivalent to do:

(1) $f_x=[f_{x1} + f_{x2}^{t_1/t_2} + f_{x3}^{t_1/t_3}]^{t/t_1}$

(2) $f_x=(f_{x1} + [f_{x2} + f_{x3}^{t_2/t_3}]^{t_1/t_2})^{t/d1}$

where $(f_{xi} + f_{xj})$ = convolution of $(f_{xi})$ and $(f_{xj})$

?

I think it should. I did a code but I get consistent differences between values `F=fx(y)` determined using (1) and (2), about 0,4% differences being `F(2)>F(1)`. Maybe this comes from numerical integration...
Thank you

Comment: perhaps you'll get better answers if you make the equations human-readable. i started editing to render them in LaTeX but that's more your job than mine :)

Comment: Done in latex...